# A field between $k$ and a finitely generated $k$-algebra is algebraic over $k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Question**:  Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra with no zero-divisors.  If $L$ is a field between $k$ and $A$, what is the easiest way to see that $L$ is algebraic over $k$?

**Motivation:**
One of the first theorems of the dimension theory in algebraic geometry is that the Krull dimension (that is, the length of the longest chain of prime ideals with indexing starting from zero) of  $A$ is the same as the transcendence degree of the fraction field $K(A)$ over $k$.   It was interesting to me that one side of this identity does not contain the base field $k$, and thus a trivial consequence of the theorem is that any subfield $L$ lying between $k$ and $K(A)$ must be algebraic over $k$, else $L$ contains a transcendental element, and the transcendence degree of $K(A)$ over $L$ is strictly smaller than that of $K(A)$ over $k$ despite both being equal to the Krull dimension of $A$.

This seems like something that could be seen more easily than via this somewhat deep theorem.  Initially it evokes the version of the Nullstellensatz that states that if $L$ is a finitely generated $k$ algebra, then it is finite as a $k$ module and *a fortiori* algebraic.  But a sub-algebra of a finitely generated $k$ algebra needn't be finitely generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ be a maximal ideal. Then $L\cap \mathfrak{m}=0$, so $L$ injects in to $A/\mathfrak{m}$, which is a finite extension of $k$ by Zariski's lemma. As subextensions of finite extensions are again finite, we're finished. (Note that we don't need any assumption on $A$ besides being a finitely-generated $k$-algebra.)